# Can't re-initialize jQuery UI tabs after clone with CloneYa plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, clone, jquery-cloneya

I'm using the [CloneYa plugin](https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya) to clone a part of a form. The part that is cloned contains a block of [jQuery UI Tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to initialize the function for the cloned tabs, instead they switch the content in the original tab block when I click them.

```
$('#formclone').cloneya({
        limit       : 20,
        cloneThis       : '.formPack',
        valueClone      : false,
        dataClone       : false,
        deepClone       : false,
        cloneButton     : '.clone',
        deleteButton    : '.delete',
        clonePosition   : 'after',
        serializeID         : true
    }).on('clone_after_append', function(event, toclone, newclone) {
        $(toclone).children('.tab-container').hide();
        $(toclone).children('.preview').show().effect('highlight', {}, 1000);
        var idNum = $(newclone).children('.preview').attr('id').replace(/preview/, '');
        $('#tab-container' + idNum).tabs();
});
```

What I'm trying to do with the lines:

```
var idNum = $(newclone).children('.preview').attr('id').replace(/preview/, '');
$('#tab-container' + idNum).tabs();
```

is to get the id of the .preview div of the new clone (for example #preview1), strip out the preview part and this way get the id of the clone.

Then I would like to run the tab function with this container id.

Not getting it to work though.

Is there another way I should do this, or another way I can get the id and run the function?

**Edit:** Here's a form example:

```
<div id="formclone">
<div id="formPack" class="formPack">
<div id="preview" class="preview">
Test
</div>

<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
<ul class="etabs">
<li class="text"><a href="#text" class="textTab" title="Lägg till text"><i><span>Lägg till text</span></i></a></li>
<li class="bild"><a href="#bild" class="bildTab" title="Ladda upp bild"><i><span>Ladda upp bild</span></i></a></li>
<li class="video"><a href="#video" class="videoTab" title="Infoga video"><i><span>Infoga video</span></i></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="text" class="text-container">
Test
</div>

<div id="bild" class="bild-container">
Test
<a href="#" class="clone">clone</a>
<a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
</div>

<div id="video" class="video-container">
Test
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have also added this function to the CloneYa plugin, to update to href of the tabs:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if (href) {
                    // match the id with the regex to get the string part
                    // separate from the number part 
                    var match = href.match(regex);

                    // if there was a number
                    if (match && match.length === 3) {
                        // just take the string part
                        // add the new number to it
                        $(this).attr('href', match[1] + j);
                    } else {
                        // else there was no number,
                        // this was earlier the first element
                        // just add the number to its id
                        $(this).attr('href', href + j);
                    }
                }
```

...and here's the document ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.preview').hide();
$('#tab-container').tabs();
});
```

Thanks!
// Jens.

Comment: Please provide the minimal HTML/CSS as well to reproduce this. read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have added some more info! Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: I tried replicating this, but whenever I click the clone button, a new line `test` appears. Can you replicate the issue in an online demo such as inbuilt code snippet or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.preview').hide();
    $('.tab-container').tabs();
});
```

and

```
$('#formclone').cloneya({

    // .... options

}).on('clone_after_append', function(event, toclone, newclone) {

    // .... other stuff

    $(newclone).find('.tab-container').tabs();

});
```